# Maxima and Minima of $f(x,y)=x^3-y^3-2xy+6$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need to find the maxima and minima of $f(x,y)=x^3-y^3-2xy+6$.

This is what I have done:

1. Compute the partial derivates $f_x$, $f_y$:

$f_x=3x^2-2y$

$f_y=-3y^2-2x$

2. Solve the system of equations:

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
f_x=3x^2-2y=0\\ f_y=-3y^2-2x = 0
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

Once solved, these are the values for $x$ and $y$:

$x=0$: $y=0$ $\Rightarrow (0,0)$

$x=-\frac{2}{3}$: $y=\frac{2}{3} \Rightarrow (-\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3})$

3. Find $f_{xx}$, $f_{yy}$ and $f_{xy}$, and evaluate the resultant derivates at the two found points:

$f_{xx}=\begin{equation}
  \left.6x\right\vert_{(0,0),(-2/3,2/3)}^{}=0,-4
\end{equation}$

$f_{yy}=\begin{equation}
  \left.-6y\right\vert_{(0,0),(-2/3,2/3)}^{}=0,-4
\end{equation}$

$f_{xy}=\begin{equation}
  \left.0\right\vert_{(0,0),(-2/3,2/3)}^{}=0,0
\end{equation}$

4. Apply the criterion for the maxima and minima:

For the point $(0,0)$:

$$
D=\begin{vmatrix}
f_{xx} & f_{xy}\\ 
f_{xy} & f_{xx}
\end{vmatrix}
=\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0
\end{vmatrix}
=0$$

Given that $D=0$, the criterion is not conclusive.

For the point $(-2/3,2/3)$:

$$
D=\begin{vmatrix}
f_{xx} & f_{xy}\\ 
f_{xy} & f_{xx}
\end{vmatrix}
=\begin{vmatrix}
-4 & 0\\ 
0 & -4
\end{vmatrix}
=16$$

Given that $D>0$, we can conclude that $(-2/3,2/3)$ is a maxima.

Is that everything that I need to test to find the maxima and minima of multivariable function?

Comment: $D > 0$ is not enough to conclude $(-2/3, 2/3)$ is a maximum.  I recommend specifying it's because $D > 0$ and $f_{xx}(-2/3, 2/3) < 0$.  Otherwise looks fine to me.

Comment: Are you to find just *relative* max and mins? If so your approach is OK, only you'd want to do a special investigation near $(0,0)$ to decide whether $f$ might definitely not have a relative max or min there, or maybe by other means conclude it *does* have one. [When the test is inclusive more work is needed at that point.]